# Setting width of element using Javascript gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a javascript image carousel for a school project. I am in early stages of making it, however I am already running into problems.

Here is the code:

```js
class Carousel{
  constructor(selector=".carousel"){
   const number = 5;
   const autoscroll = 'off';
   const width = "100%";
   const height  = "200px";
   this.selector = document.querySelector(selector);
   this.number = (this.selector.dataset.viewNumber==undefined)? number : this.selector.dataset.viewNumber;
   this.autoScroll = (this.selector.dataset.autoscroll==undefined)? autoscroll : this.selector.dataset.autoscroll;
   this.width = (this.selector.dataset.width==undefined)? width : this.selector.dataset.width;
   this.height = (this.selector.dataset.height==undefined)? height : this.selector.dataset.height;
  }
  makeCarousel(){

   let srcList=[];
   let str = "<div class='previous'><p>&larr;</p></div><div class='rotater'>";
   let src;
   for (let i of this.selector.children){
    src = i.getAttribute("src");
    srcList.push(src);
    str= `${str}<div class='carousel-img-holder'><img src=${src} class='carousel-img' /></div>`;
   }
   str=`${str}</div><div class='next'><p>&rarr;</p></div>`;
   this.selector.innerHTML = str;
   const styler = this.selector.style;
   styler.width = this.width;
   styler.height = this.height;
   styler.display = "flex";
   const rotate = this.selector.childNodes[1];
   rotate.style.display = "flex";
   rotate.style.height = "100%";
   rotate.style.width = "100%";
   rotate.style.overflow = "scroll";
   for (let i of this.selector.childNodes[1].childNodes){
    let height = this.selector.getBoundingClientRect().height+"px";
    let width = (this.selector.getBoundingClientRect().width/this.number)+"px";
    i.setAttribute('style',`height: ${height};width: ${width}`);
    i.childNodes[0].style.maxWidth = "100%";
    i.childNodes[0].style.maxWidth = "100%";
   }
  }

 }

 const carousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
 carousel.makeCarousel();
 console.log("Width from getBoundingClientRect: "+document.querySelector(".carousel-img-holder").getBoundingClientRect().width)
  console.log("Width from css style: "+document.querySelector(".carousel-img-holder").style.width)
```

```html
<body style="background: #444">
 <div id="carousel" data-view-number=7 data-autoscroll="on" data-width="100%" data-height="200px">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/001.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/002.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/003.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/004.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/006.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/007.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/009.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/010.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/011.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/012.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/013.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/014.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/015.png">
 </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to show only the number of images mentioned in the `data-view-number` attribute on one page at a time. So I am calculating the width of the outer div from `getBoundingClientRect().width`, dividing it by the `data-view-number` value and assigning it to the style attribute using `setAttribute`. However, it is not coming out as desired. So I checked the width of the object. In google dev tools, it is showing that the style is applied correctly. So I tried to get it by `getBoundingClientRect()` and it shows a different width altogether. Is it because I am using percentage widths on the parent? I tried changing it to pixel width but it did not work.

I printed out both the values of the width in the console. As you can see, these two widths are not coming out to be equal. I don't understand why. I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Any pointers are appreciated. I don't know if this would have been easier in jquery but I want to avoid it because our professor told us to avoid using jquery if possible.

Comment: Check widths at the Computed tab of devtools or  use `windows.getComputedStyle(DOMObject, propertyName)`. This will show if there are other properties influencing your results.

Comment: window.getComputedStyle(DOMObject).width gives me the value of the width but I don't understand how I am supposed to use it for debugging @zer00ne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not taking into account the widths of next and prev divs. You should subtract that also from the width of carousel.

Basically the logic should be

```
widthOfImg = (Totalwidth - Width of previous div - Width of next div )/this.number
```

Also add the following style

```
body {
    margin :0;
}
```

Also changed this line

```
rotate.style.width = "calc(100% - 32px)";
```

Also instead of applying max-width to the image, apply the same width to the image that you are adding on `carousel-img-holder` div

```
i.childNodes[0].style.width= width ;
```

See the updated code below

```js
class Carousel{
  constructor(selector="#carousel"){
   const number = 5;
   const autoscroll = 'off';
   const width = "100%";
   const height  = "200px";
   this.selector = document.querySelector(selector);
   this.number = (this.selector.dataset.viewNumber==undefined)? number : this.selector.dataset.viewNumber;
   this.autoScroll = (this.selector.dataset.autoscroll==undefined)? autoscroll : this.selector.dataset.autoscroll;
   this.width = (this.selector.dataset.width==undefined)? width : this.selector.dataset.width;
   this.height = (this.selector.dataset.height==undefined)? height : this.selector.dataset.height;
  }
  makeCarousel(){

   let srcList=[];
   let str = "<div class='previous'><p>&larr;</p></div><div class='rotater'>";
   let src;
   for (let i of this.selector.children){
    src = i.getAttribute("src");
    srcList.push(src);
    str= `${str}<div class='carousel-img-holder'><img src=${src} class='carousel-img' /></div>`;
   }
   str=`${str}</div><div class='next'><p>&rarr;</p></div>`;
   this.selector.innerHTML = str;
   const styler = this.selector.style;
   styler.width = this.width;
   styler.height = this.height;
   styler.display = "flex";
   const rotate = this.selector.childNodes[1];
   rotate.style.display = "flex";
   rotate.style.height = "100%";
   rotate.style.width = "calc(100% - 32px)";
   for (let i of this.selector.childNodes[1].childNodes){
    let height = this.selector.getBoundingClientRect().height+"px";
    let width = ( (this.selector.getBoundingClientRect().width - document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width - document.getElementsByClassName('previous')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width ) /this.number)+"px";

    i.setAttribute('style',`height: ${height};width: ${width}`);
    i.childNodes[0].style.width= width ;
    i.childNodes[0].style.width= width ;
   }
  }

 }

 const carousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
 carousel.makeCarousel();
```

```html
<body style="background: #444;margin:0;">
 <div id="carousel" data-view-number=7 data-autoscroll="on" data-width="100%" data-height="200px">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/001.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/002.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/003.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/004.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/006.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/007.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/009.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/010.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/011.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/012.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/013.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/014.png">
  <img src="https://swachhcoin.com/img/015.png">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem as it shows in your snippet.

Comment: Still not fixed actually. Checking the width from getClientBoundingRect() and the width from style.width are very different. My final goal is to show only the number of images that are specified in this.number in the viewport. If you have a better method for doing that, it would be helpful too.

Comment: Upddated answer, please check if this is what you want...?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Could you elaborate your answer a bit more if possible to explain what changes you did?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check.